# Do keys with different hashes also get mapped to the same index in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, collision

Looking at the code specifically line 393, it looks like different hashes have been mapped to same index. I had an understanding that the hashcode is used to determine what bucket in a HashMap is to be used, and the bucket is made up of a linked list of all the entries with the same hashcode. They why have the `e.hash == hash` check ?

```
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (key == null)
            return putForNullKey(value);
        int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
        int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
        for (Entry e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
            Object k;
            if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
                V oldValue = e.value;
                e.value = value;
                e.recordAccess(this);
                return oldValue;
            }
        }
        modCount++;
        addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: There are 4 billion different hash values, but typically rather fewer buckets. So objects with different hash values may still end up in the same bucket. (If there are `N` buckets, then the bucket index is typically chosen as `o.hashCode() % N`.)

Comment: Also, comparing hash codes is very fast (they're just `int`s), while comparing objects for equality can be quite slow. If the hash codes are different the objects cannot be equal, so it's a win to skip the call to `equals()` in that case.

Comment: It's actually `h & (length-1)` since length is always a power of 2, but who's counting? =)

Answer (score 2):

Since a hashcode can be one in 2^32 values, it is rare that the hashmap has so many buckets (just the table would require 16GB of memory). So yes, you can have objects with different hashes in the same buckets of the maps (AFAIK it is a simple modulus operation of `hachCode % numberOfBuckets`).

Note that the code does not use directly `key.hashCode()`, but `hash(key.hashCode())`.

Answer (score 1):

This check is an optimization taking into account for collisions.
You can have 2 elements that have the same hash key (due to collision) and as a result are mapped to the same bucket. Same key different actual elements.
So if `e.hash != hash` you don't need to check for equality (which could be an expensive operation)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is surprisingly YES. I put Sysout's in the code of put() to observe it's behaviour

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
        System.out.println("Put: Table empty. Inflating table to threshold:" + threshold);
        inflateTable(threshold);
    }
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key);
    System.out.println("Put: Key not null:" + hash);
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    System.out.println("Put: Obtained index:" + i);
    for (Entry<K, V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        System.out.println("Put: Iteraing over table[" + i + "] elements");
        Object k;
        System.out.println("Put: Checking if hash & key are equal");
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Put: Incrementing modCounter");
    modCount++;
    System.out.println("Put: Adding a new Entry[hash="
            + hash + ", key=" + key + ", value="
            + value + ", i=" + i + "]");
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

And then tested with the following inputs,

```
MyHashMap p = new MyHashMap<>();
p.put(0, "Z");
p.put(1, "A");
p.put(17, "A");
```

And guess what the output comes

```
Put: Table empty. Inflating table to threshold:16
Inflate: RoundUpPowerOf2 of size=16
Inflate: Setting Min of [capacity * loadFactor, MAXIMUM_CAPACITY + 1] as threshold
Inflate: Given values[capacity=16, loadfactor=0.75, MAXIMUM_CAPACITY=1073741824
Creating array of Entry[] with size:16
Put: Key not null:0
IndexFor: calculating index for [given hash=0, length=16]
Put: Obtained index:0
Put: Incrementing modCounter
Put: Adding a new Entry[hash=0, key=0, value=Z, i=0]
Put: Key not null:1
IndexFor: calculating index for [given hash=1, length=16]
Put: Obtained index:1
Put: Incrementing modCounter
Put: Adding a new Entry[hash=1, key=1, value=A, i=1]
Put: Key not null:16
IndexFor: calculating index for [given hash=16, length=16]
Put: Obtained index:0
Put: Iteraing over table[0] elements
Put: Incrementing modCounter
Put: Adding a new Entry[hash=16, key=17, value=A, i=0]
```

So, as you can see, two entries got stored in the same index. Was very excited to see such behaviour. Inquisitively trying to get an answer for this.